# How can I find $\theta$ where $\sin \theta=X$ and $\cos \theta=Y$?

Tags: trigonometry

I have two variables, $X$ and $Y$. Both are between $-1$ and $1$, inclusive, but I need to find the angle, of which the sine is $X$, and the cosine is $Y$. How can I do that? This is probably a dumb question but it's been troubling me for a while now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to check if $X^2+Y^2=1$. Iff it's true, then they are sine and cosine of the angle $\theta=\arctan({X \over Y})+k\pi \;\forall k\in \Bbb Z$.

Comment: Or $\arctan(X/Y) \pm \pi$.

Comment: It won't quite work if $Y=0$.

Comment: @JCAA Right, but $Y=0$ i.e. $\cos(\theta)=0$ the angle is quite obvious

Comment: @JCAA You can't divide by 0, so is there a solution that is safe?

Comment: You can just take the case separately that ${Y=0}$. Or you could be naughty and just say it's ${\arctan(\pm \infty)}$ giving you ${\pm\frac{\pi}{2}}$ xD

Comment: The safest way right now is washing hands, wearing masks and keeping social distance. Not dividing by 0 also helps.

Comment: @JCAA This made me laugh way harder than it should have

Comment: @JamesA If you want $X=\sin(\theta)$ and $Y = \cos(\theta)$, then $\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) = 1$ gives you no choice.

Comment: @RobertIsrael or $\arctan({X \over Y}) + k\pi \;\forall k\in \Bbb Z$ if we want to be reeeaaally pedantic.

Comment: @Flutterblaxi My point is that with $\tan(\theta)=X/Y$, you could have either $\sin(\theta)=X$ and $\cos(\theta)=Y$ or $\sin(\theta)=-X$ and $\cos(\theta)=-Y$.